# SKSpriteNode- game in swift 2 (xcode beta 7)

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm trying to do a rectangle object (just the walls, with nothing inside), so I declare

```
var wall= SKSpriteNode()
wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: frame).
```

However, I want to do a smaller rectangle, say with `width = self.frame.width/2` and `height = self.frame.height/2`, with the center = center of the screen, and with some linewitdh and color in the wall. Is this possible with SKSpriteNote? And if so, how can I do this?

Comment: yes it is possible. it will be another sprite node. when u say line width, and border color, you can try skshape node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let ctrPoint = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)

    let outerRect = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(self.size.width-80, self.size.height-80))
    outerRect.position = ctrPoint
    addChild(outerRect)

    let innerRect = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.grayColor(), size: CGSizeMake(self.size.width-100, self.size.height-100))
    innerRect.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: innerRect.frame)
    innerRect.position = ctrPoint
    addChild(innerRect)

    let bounceSprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
    bounceSprite.position = ctrPoint
    bounceSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bounceSprite.size)
    bounceSprite.physicsBody!.restitution = 1.0
    addChild(bounceSprite)
}
```